# Change MCP23017 values from true/false to 1/0s

Tags: raspbian

I have a Raspberry Pi using a MCP23017 and also the Adafruit MCP23017 library. It works well but I am wondering if there is a way to tell the mcp() to change the pin mode from true/false to 1s/0s.

Currently, my python is looking for highs(1) and lows(0) and not trues and falses.

Before I go and change all my code to look for true and false when it reads a pin I was just wondering if there is a command to change it to 1/0s?

Right now this prints false:

print(mcp.input(14))

I'd love for it to say 0 :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Convert the boolean value to an integer:

```
print(int(mcp.input(14)))
```

Answer (score 1):

This is nothing to do with the MCP23017 chip (or the Raspberry Pi).

If you want to change this you will have to change the Adafruit MCP23017 library module and alter the way it defines the "mcp" object.